# Datepicker beforeShowDay Tooltip click instead of hover?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using datepicker with beforeshowday to highlight a range of days and display information about the relevant day in a tooltip. The problem is, I'm developing for a mobile device so hover isn't available. Is there any way to have the tooltip appear on click instead?

Here's my code:

```
    var date1 = new Date(2014, 6, 6);
    var date2 = new Date(2014, 6, 17);

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
          var text = "Holiday";
          if (date >= date1 && date <= date2) {
            return [true, 'highlight', text];
          }
          return [true, '', ''];
        }
      });
    });
```

I also tried including qtip and added this code to the end of my current script, which didn't help.

```
  $('[title]').qtip({ show: 'click' })
```

Comment: denote the parent or contain element of the attribute title

Comment: $('span[title]').qtip({ show: 'click' })  like this

Comment: You mean $('td[title]')? Because I tried that with the same results.